# Disk space report create HTML and add server list to email

Tags: html, powershell, foreach, diskspace

I have a very long script I am working with and the part that isn't working has got me a bit perplexed.

In short, the script looks for all server OS, checks all disk space, color codes certain ones if they meet a criteria, outputs it to HTML (I can't email HTML files as they are blocked, so had to go this way) then it adds a list of server that meet a criteria to the body of an email and sends the email.

Everything is working except "then it adds a list of server that meet a criteria to the body of an email and sends the email" it only adds the last server on the list to the email.

Here is a snippet of the script that I am having issues with.

The first part is what does the math and figures the percentage and that works just fine and adds to the HTML report just fine.

The second part is the part that doesn't add to the email correctly. I only get the last server from the list that meets the criteria of free space less than 5%. I am sure I am just over looking something. Any ideas?

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -Like "*Server*"' | Sort DNSHostName | ForEach-Object { 
    ### Get the hostname of the machine
    #$hostname = Get-WmiObject -Impersonation Impersonate -ComputerName $_ -Query "SELECT Name From Win32_ComputerSystem"
    #$name = $hostname.Name.ToUpper()
    $name = $_.DNSHostName.ToUpper()
    Add-Content $html_file ('<Table id="dataTable"><tr><td colspan="3" class="serverName">' + $name + '</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="headings">Drive Letter</td><td class="headings">Total Size</td><td class="headings">Free Space</td><td class="headings">Percent Free</td></tr>')

    ### Get the drives of the machine
    $drives = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "drivetype=3" -ComputerName $name -Impersonation Impersonate

    ####loop through and add to html report
#####Edited portion of script below#########
 ForEach ($drive in $drives) {
        $space_color = ""
        $free_space = $drive.FreeSpace
        $percent = ($drive.FreeSpace/$drive.size*100)
        $percent = [Math]::Round($percent, 2)
        If ($percent -le 1) {
            $space_color = $Critical_space
            }
            elseif ($percent -le 5) {
            $space_color = $very_low_space
            }
            elseif ($percent -le 10) {
            $space_color = $low_space
                            }
            elseif ($percent -le 15) {
            $space_color = $medium_space
            }

        If ($percent -lt 5) {$addtobody += $name,$drive.deviceid,$Percent,"%"}
```

Comment: Dunno the syntax for Powershell, but I would assume that your function overwrites the $addtobody on each iteration of the foreach (leaving the last one), instead of adding to the $addtobody via .= or += or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it `$addtobody` gets added to the email at some point in the code not presented right?  if so then you just need to turn that into an array and add elements to it rather than setting it equal to the element. (also assuming that the two missing `}` are just cut off of what you've copied, I've added them in but be sure not to double them up in your script)

```
$addtobody = @()
ForEach ($drive in $drives) {
    $space_color = ""
    $free_space = $drive.FreeSpace
    $percent = ($drive.FreeSpace/$drive.size*100)
    $percent = [Math]::Round($percent, 2)
    If ($percent -le 1) {
        $space_color = $Critical_space
        }
        elseif ($percent -le 5) {
        $space_color = $very_low_space
        }
        elseif ($percent -le 10) {
        $space_color = $low_space
                        }
        elseif ($percent -le 15) {
        $space_color = $medium_space
        }


   ForEach ($drive in $drives) {
    $free_space = $drive.FreeSpace
    $percent = ($drive.FreeSpace/$drive.size*100)
    $percent = [Math]::Round($percent, 2)
    If ($percent -le 5) {$addtobody += $name,$drive.deviceid,$Percent,"%"}
   }
}
```

Comment: you were right for the most part.  
    $addtobody = @() 
higher up in the script did the trick for that part but it started duplicating all the results in the HTML out-file
i made the edits below and now it lists them in the email the way i wanted it to - i added the new code to the script above

Answer (score 1):

I failed in my initial post to point out that $addtobody should be defined above your outer loop:

```
$addtobody = @()
```

On the last line, try changing $addtobody to *+=*.

```
if ($percent -le 5) {
       $addtobody += $name,$drive.deviceid,$Percent,"%"
}
```

This adds the value to what exists, vs. setting the value. Each iteration of your loop (as currently written), you are re-assigning the value to $addtobody.

After considering your HTML email limitation, you could also try experimenting with sending a text-based table. The below snippet would come outside of your loop.

```
$emailBody = $addtobody | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String
```